# Accidentally marked an email as "phishing"

Tags: gmail

I received an email and I marked it as "Phishing". Now I can no longer receive an email from a particular sender. I went to see if I get their email in the All Mail  or Spam label and nothing is there.

I tried googling but there is no concrete solution. It is less than 15 days since this has happened. I tried Google forums but could not find a definite answer on Gmail. How can I recover that email, please?

Comment: Add details like the solutions you already tried and the link to your post in the Google Product Forums.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instruction at [Legitimate mail is marked as spam - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9008?hl=en)

> If you find a message wrongly classified as spam, you can unmark the
>   message. Just select the message, and click the **Not Spam** button that
>   appears at the top and bottom of your current view. Unmarking a
>   message will automatically move it to your inbox.
>
> If you find that some senders' messages are consistently being
>   mislabeled as spam, you can prevent this by:
>
> - [Adding their email addresses](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8933) to your Contacts list. Gmail will deliver
>     messages from members of your Contacts list to your inbox, unless we
>     know with high confidence that they are spam.
> - Some messages sent from
>     contacts which are very clearly spam can be sent directly to your Spam
>     label. More importantly, in some cases messages from contacts will not
>     be sent to Spam but will be marked with a [red warning banner](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1074268) if the
>     content is suspicious - for example, your friend's or contact's
>     account has been compromised and used to send [phishing messages](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8253).
> - Creating a filter so the messages are never sent to Spam.